# How do I mock an ADO connection?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, mocking, delphi-xe2, ado

I'm trying to figure out how to mock a `TADOConnection` (working with Delpi XE2 and SQL server). The thing is that for unit testing I'd like to be able to fake out the connection and populate the datasets with static data instead of data from the database. So that when I do this,

```
ADOQuery.Connection := FakeADOConn;  
ADOQuery.SQL.Add(SQLStr);
```

, there would just be a lookup, matching `SQLStr` to some predefined data in a textfile (I'm thinking XML).

```
Textfile -> FakeTADOConnection -> TADODataset -> Data source -> Data Control
```

However when I've googled I've not been able to find anything on the topic, which makes me suspicious that I'm completely off, and this whole thing is a stupid idea.

So could someone explain to me how one go about faking a ADO connection or, alternatively, why wanting to do so is a ridiculous idea?

Comment: I don´t consider the idea ridiculous, but I believe it will be kind of hard to make it work, just because you will have to implement all the IADOConnection methods. However, after done, this could indeed help you to build really good test cases.

Comment: @AlexSC Same situation, as post, once, consider your answer, but, I had to rejected, due to the project priority, and lack of time and coumentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class like this:

```
type
  TMockADOConnection = class(TInterfacedObject, IADOConnection)
    // Declare here all the interface methods
  end;
```

Then you will have to implement **all** the IADOConnection interface methods.

Comment: Thanks! I feel kinda stupid; this answer is so simple but it _is_ the answer to my question (which is why I accepted it). I will however go with Paul Mitchells approach and am currently reading up on the repository pattern in Fowlers Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find the Repository Pattern useful here.